# How to add our own graph to Kibana?

Tags: highcharts, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am using Kibana and logstash with elastic search to analyse the log data. 
I have also prepared a few customized chart using highchart,logstash and elastic search. I want to display these highchart charts on my kibana UI.

Please suggest me how to do that.

Comment: replicate this issue as live example on jsFiddle, please

Comment: just wondering - why can't you change the HTML and perhaps add a div for the highchart section?

Comment: Kibana is realy strict in what you can and what you cant do in it. You can only use the Graphs provided by Kibana, you can however as ali haider suggested, add your graphs to the dom

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/788):

> The project is entirely open source, you're welcome to fork it and make changes as you see fit, however we do not build in any support for bringing in new libraries.

You can be inspired by [this other issue](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/pull/1236) that imported the d3.js library to build word cloud panels.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but anyway I wanted to contribute. It sure is possible to extend Kibana visualizations. I have created two Visualization Plugins for Kibana 4.4.1. One is a Sunburst chart and another a circle packing chart (Both D3). Check them out in [circles](https://github.com/JuanCarniglia/kbn_circles_vis) and [sunburst](https://github.com/JuanCarniglia/kbn_sunburst_vis). Let me know what you think and if you think of another chart that might be useful.

Update!: Another vis! [BoxPlot](https://github.com/JuanCarniglia/kbn_boxplot_vis)

Comment: I did move these 2 projects of yours sunburst and circles on our Kibana instance and they worked well. I am trying to get this http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/bundle.html into Kibana. That D3 project seems to be working on my localhost and I transported all JS/ HTMl over. Is there any easy way I can get this into Kibana by following your architecture for the 2 projects you built easily. I assume I will have to power learn D3/ Angular and node right? if this needs to go into Kibana and scale and stuff?

Comment: It is possible. You have to fiddle a little with the object returned from Elasticsearch, to get it into the JSON format expected by the D3 visualization. But it can definitely be done. Let me know if you want to outsource it :)